# Why this simple ruby code does not work in the commandline, but does when pasting it in irb

Tags: ruby, timeout

I have the following code:

sample_code.rb

```
class Foo
  def bar
    Timeout.timeout(0.5){
        puts "Interupt this if it takes longer then 0.5 seconds"
    }
  end
end

foo = Foo.new()
foo.bar
```

The example above works when you paste it in irb,
but when you place it in a script and run it like this:

```
ruby ./sample_code.rb
```

It will give the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from ./irb_works_ruby_dont.rb:11:in `<main>'
./irb_works_ruby_dont.rb:4:in `bar': uninitialized constant Foo::Timeout (NameError)
```

Is this a Timeout issue? Does `irb` load some modules that the normal `ruby` command doesn't? How to make the code work when run as a script?

Comment: BTW, on the command line you would run it by `ruby ./sample_code.rb`, not `irb ./sample_code.rb`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explaination is that IRB requires Timeout when it starts up the REPL - but your script file is being executed before that happens. You can fix it by simply requiring it:

```
require 'timeout'

class Foo
  def bar
    Timeout.timeout(0.5){
        puts "Interupt this if it takes longer then 0.5 seconds"
    }
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
```

Comment: The long answer is that IRB loads quite a lot of stuff and has a few dependencies of its own. https://github.com/ruby/irb/blob/master/lib/irb.rb